# File looks different when I print it via Python

Tags: python, file, character-encoding

I have a file with name `sample.txt`, I am trying to read it byte by byte but I cannot understand why it does not match with the input file.

When I read first 20 bytes of the file by

```
with open("sample.txt", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read(20)
    print data
```

It prints out that:

```
�П�NsM�<�x]��%�-���
```

Here is the first line of my original file

```
êÐŸòNsM<éx]ßÁ%™-‡ôãK—j  Ê”/,:d­óâ½…i4/î¸á­8Û2¡ŒÚž3sõIßŸ·ÝÅ.}‰pL~áÉK¨LìØÌ³’/fÁ2Ëõ‰é½'‡å×ñ—ú÷ôÜÑGÃK¥–±‡ôÌk¡4 Ô>™h·YÊ¸ãjU…n~e|–¶(1œÌÜ‚”,¸”ô™ÍŽô³å1¥Æ‹Š¤{´%Ë§rKp1Õ‘•îá–ÿ³˜¼¶ç)9NHõ
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you printing it out onto? The console may not support the characters used.

Comment: I am printing it onto the Linux terminal.

Comment: What is the encoding of the original file? In python it defaults to `UTF-8`.

Comment: @selubamih Python 3 has more consistent string handling.

Comment: Is it true that both will behave the same if I convert files to byte arrays?

Comment: you can also try `encoding = 'latin-1'`